# how to define StackGres helm chart "restapi" values to use internal LoadBalancer - AWS EKS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I am trying to install the "StackGres" using helm chart defined on their website (https://stackgres.io/install/)
I have pulled the chart in my local and trying to modify the Service type to "LoadBalancer" and adding "annotations" to enable the internal LoadBalancer.

I have tried to supply the below file content using helm upgrade command, but this is not creating the Internal LoadBalancer(in my private subnet)

`helm upgrade --install stackgres-operator stackgres-charts/stackgres-operator \ --namespace stackgres \ --values new-val.yaml`

```
restapi:
  serviceAccount:
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: true
  service:
    annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: true


adminui:
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
```